# Search then sort value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, search

I try to search value with condition then sort all value avalible.But when I'm sort all values was be reset.
This is my select mysql
`SELECT * FROM tbProduct WHERE name = '%ASUS%'`
.Value return is
`1 - Asus TUF, 5 - Asus zep, 7 - Asus`
And then I'm click Sort
mysql return
`SELECT * FROM tbProduct ORDER BY id DESC`.But not is: `SELECT * FROM tbProduct WHERE name = '%ASUS%' ORDER BY id DESC`
and value return is
`9 - Asus TUF, 8 - Linux, 7 - Asus, 6 - MSI, 5 - Asus zep, 4 - MacBook, 3 - DELL, 2 - ACER, 1 - Asus`
Is there any way I can sort my search results? If you have ideas please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it looks like you are clicking sort after results are fetched. That runs another query and the previous one is lost.

To get the desired results you have to use the Sort statement in the first query itself.

That means you have to run.

```
SELECT * FROM tbProduct WHERE name = '%ASUS%' ORDER BY id DESC;
```

In first place. Don't expect to run one query and then another on any GUI based interactions with databases and hope that it will return a subset of your result from the new query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `id` values look like:

```
9 - Asus TUF
```

You could try sorting using only the numerical component:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbProduct
WHERE name = '%ASUS%'
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id, ' ', 1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: I mean,when click SORT, Search Value was clear so " WHERE name = '%ASUS%'" not work anymore

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  At this point, you should include clear sample table data in your question along with the desired output.